# Logical Operators in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

My goal is to count how many matches are in Column A and Column B

```
answer = length(which(DF$A=="English" & which(DF$B=="English")))
```

I get an error with this attempt. What's the correct way to write this line of code in R?

Comment: you don't need the second `which`, and `sum(DF$A == 'English' & DF$B == 'English')` should also work if you aren't counting each column individually

Comment: alternatively, you can use intersect: length(intersect(which(...), which(...)))

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of rows where **both A and B** has 'English',
you can use `sum`. To get the corresponding row numbers use `which` as below:

```
# Number of rows
sum(DF$A == 'English' & DF$B == 'English')
# Row numbers 
which(DF$A == 'English' & DF$B == 'English')
```

Similarly, if you are interested in the case where at **least one of the A and B** has this word then use;

```
sum(DF$A == 'English' | DF$B == 'English')
which(DF$A == 'English' | DF$B == 'English')
```

Example

```
DF
#          A       B
# 1  English English
# 2  English English
# 3  English English
# 4  English English
# 5  English English
# 6  English       p
# 7  English       q
# 8  English       r
# 9        i       s
# 10       j       t
    
sum(DF$A == 'English' & DF$B == 'English')
#[1] 5

sum(DF$A == 'English' | DF$B == 'English')
#[1] 8
```

---

You can use `which` to get the row numbers

```
which(DF$A == 'English' & DF$B == 'English')
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

which(DF$A == 'English' | DF$B == 'English')
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

---

**Data**

```
DF <- structure(list(A = c("English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "i", "j"),
                     B = c("English", "English", "English", "English", "English", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t")), class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```